# npm cant change Jasmine package version

Tags: npm, jasmine

if I run `npm view jasmine version` or `npm view jasmine version -g` from `~` the version returned is `3.3.1`

I need the version to be `2.8.0` so i try to downgrade with `npm install jasmine@2.8.0 -g` but `npm view jasmine version` is still `3.3.1`

Now if i do `npm list -g` i see the correct version for jasmine (`2.8.0`)... So where is the 3.3.1 coming from?

```
    ├─┬ jasmine@2.8.0
    │ ├── exit@0.1.2
    │ ├─┬ glob@7.1.3
    │ │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
    │ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
    │ │ │ ├── once@1.4.0 deduped
    │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
    │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
    │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4
    │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.11
    │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0
    │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
    │ │ ├─┬ once@1.4.0
    │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 deduped
    │ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
    │ └── jasmine-core@2.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding the `npm view` command:**

When you run either of the following [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html) commands:

```
npm view jasmine version
```

or

```
npm view jasmine version -g
```

you are sending a `GET` request to the npm registry. More specifically you are sending a request to the following endpoint:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine
```

You can verify this by appending the [`-d`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties) option to your command for additional logging information. For instance, if you run;

```
npm view jasmine version -d
```

you'll see additional information in your log which includes something like the following:

> `npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine`

*Note: This line above indicates the endpoint which your `view` command is making the request to.*

---

**So where is the 3.3.1 coming from?**

`3.3.1` is the latest version of the *jasmine* package available in the npm registry. The result of any `view` command does not indicate information about packages installed on your system, instead it returns information (metadata) about packages held in the npm registry.

You'll continue to see version  `3.3.1` logged to your console when running;

```
npm view jasmine version
```

(from any directory location on your system), until a newer version of `jasmine` is published to the npm registry.

---

**Additional Notes:**

1. The two npm commands that you are running, namely:

   ```
   npm view jasmine version
   ```

   and

   ```
   npm view jasmine version -g
   ```

   are effectively the same command. The `view` command does not provide a `-g` option. The `-g` option is simply being ignored.
2. The [`npm list`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html) command, (as you've already discovered), should be utilized for retrieving information about packages that are installed on your system. Hence that why its indicating your expected result(s).